# call': ERR Invalid IP address in MEET (Redis::CommandError) Redis

Tags: redis, node-redis, redistogo

When i excute the redis cluster command fr first time i am getting below error

```
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 2 nodes...
M: a644f0c711c6a7a455f4154682beb0866df0c1e5 10.1.0.164:1234
   slots:0-8191 (8192 slots) master
M: 3d057397fbafc5a29a5c9aacffec70b3b356cbed 10.1.2.68:1112
slots:8192-16383 (8192 slots) master
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
>>> Nodes configuration updated
>>> Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:85:in `call': ERR Invalid      IP address in MEET (Redis::CommandError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:2240:in `method_missing'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:2239:in `method_missing'
from ./redis-trib.rb:495:in `join_cluster'
from ./redis-trib.rb:493:in `each'
from ./redis-trib.rb:493:in `join_cluster'
from ./redis-trib.rb:687:in `create_cluster_cmd'
from ./redis-trib.rb:755:in `send'
from ./redis-trib.rb:755
```

If i execute same command second time error changes to below

```
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 2 nodes...
M: b19f4a4e3fd69e905897937cb694c62ceaf47643 127.0.0.1:1112
slots:0-16383 (16384 slots) master
M: 1e93a0ccde04d9fba0403917e622e82a891b2137 10.1.0.164:1234
slots:0-16383 (16384 slots) master
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:85:in `call': ERR Slot     10247 is already busy (Redis::CommandError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:2240:in `method_missing'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:2239:in `method_missing'
from ./redis-trib.rb:184:in `flush_node_config'
from ./redis-trib.rb:476:in `flush_nodes_config'
from ./redis-trib.rb:475:in `each'
from ./redis-trib.rb:475:in `flush_nodes_config'
from ./redis-trib.rb:684:in `create_cluster_cmd'
from ./redis-trib.rb:755:in `send'
from ./redis-trib.rb:755
```

Please help me to solve both issues.

If there any tutorial for dummies for Redis cluster configuration share with me please.